# T-SQL Last date of previous fortnight, catering for year transition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a date dimension table, which has for each date record a large number of fields, one of which is the fortnight of year.

I am trying to write a T-SQL query to return the last date of the previous fortnight and the previous fortnight number, based on the current date (or any date passed to it).

I can get the current fortnight and last date ok, what I need to figure out is how to get the previous fortnight end date, including over the transition to a new year.

The code I have below works to return the current fortnight of the year and the last date of that fortnight, how would I modify this to return the previous fortnight and end date of that fortnight for any date, particularly if the date was say the 2nd Jan in any year?

```
With
    Query1 As 
    (Select 
     Cast(GetDate() As Date) As Todays_Date)
Select
    Query1.Todays_Date,
    staging.dbo.manualdata_DateDimension.FortnightofYear,
    Max(staging.dbo.manualdata_DateDimension.Date) As Max_Date
From
    Query1 Inner Join
    staging.dbo.manualdata_DateDimension On staging.dbo.manualdata_DateDimension.Date = Query1.Todays_Date
Group By
    Query1.Todays_Date,
    staging.dbo.manualdata_DateDimension.FortnightofYear
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT FortnightofYear
          ,Date
          ,GETDATE() AS [Todays_date]
          ,ROW_NUMBER() PARTITION BY (FortnightofYear ORDER BY Date DESC) AS [RowID]          
          ,LAG(Date) PARTITION BY (FortnightofYear ORDER BY Date DESC) AS [PreviosDate]
    FROM staging.dbo.manualdata_DateDimension
    WHERE Date <= GETDATE()
)
SELECT *
FROM DataSource 
WHERE ([RowID] = 1 AND Date = [Todays_date])
    OR ([RowID] = 2 AND [PreviosDate] = [Todays_date])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It assumes `FortnightofYear` starts over every year from 1

```
DECLARE @DateToSearch datetime = GetDate() ---- set this to the date to be searched

; WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        t.Year
        , t.FortnightofYear
        , FirstDate = MIN(t.Date)
        , LastDate  = MAX(t.Date)
    FROM 
        staging.dbo.manualdata_DateDimension t
    GROUP BY 
        t.Year
        , t.FortnightofYear
)
SELECT
    Todays_Date                            = @DateToSearch
                                           
    , Current_FortnightofYear              = FortnightofYear  
    , Current_FortnightofYear_First_Date   = FirstDate
    , Current_FortnightofYear_Last_Date    = LastDate

    --- if no previous records, values will be NULL
    , Previous_FortnightofYear             = LAG(FortnightofYear, 1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY Year, FortnightofYear)
    , Previous_FortnightofYear_First_Date  = LAG(First_Date,      1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY Year, FortnightofYear)
    , Previous_FortnightofYear_Last_Date   = LAG(Last_Date,       1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY Year, FortnightofYear)
FROM 
    cte
WHERE
    @DateToSearch BETWEEN FirstDate AND LastDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both gotqn and K4M as it made me rethink how I was going about it, but neither post worked.

Here is the code that returns the required data (I hope I have tagged it correctly), passing @rundate on execution as any date.

```
With
    Query1 As (
     Select
         staging.dbo.manualdata_DateDimension.Year,
         staging.dbo.manualdata_DateDimension.FortnightofYear,
         Min(staging.dbo.manualdata_DateDimension.Date) As min_date,
         Max(staging.dbo.manualdata_DateDimension.Date) As max_date,
         Cast(DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 1, Min(staging.dbo.manualdata_DateDimension.Date)), 0) As date) As
         previous_fortnight_max_date
     From
         staging.dbo.manualdata_DateDimension
     Group By
         staging.dbo.manualdata_DateDimension.Year,
         staging.dbo.manualdata_DateDimension.FortnightofYear
     Having
         @rundate Between Min(staging.dbo.manualdata_DateDimension.Date) And
         Max(staging.dbo.manualdata_DateDimension.Date)
    )
Select
    Query1.Year,
    Query1.FortnightofYear,
    Query1.min_date,
    Query1.max_date,
    Query1.previous_fortnight_max_date,
    staging.dbo.manualdata_DateDimension.FortnightofYear As PreviousFortnightofYear
From
    Query1 Inner Join
    staging.dbo.manualdata_DateDimension On staging.dbo.manualdata_DateDimension.Date =
            Query1.previous_fortnight_max_date
```